# Scaffolded account pages not accessible

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am implementing the scaffolded identity in my ASP.NET Core application, however I can't access most of my account pages. They worked before and don't know why they are not working anymore.

I tried re-scaffolding the pages already, without success unfortunately.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

            var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
            cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("nl-NL");
                //By default the below will be set to whatever the server culture is. 
                options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("nl-NL") };
            });

            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection")));

            //Vernieuwde Identityuser manier i.v.m. Role based Authorization
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            //Login redirect juiste manier
            //services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "~/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/login");
            //services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LogoutPath = "~/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/logout");
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.AllowAreas = true;
                    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
                });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.Cookie.Name = "LoginSession";
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            });

            services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
            });
        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseRequestLocalization();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();
        }
```

Am I maybe missing some needed code in the above methods (Startup.cs)?
Can't think of any other reason as it worked before.

Comment: What is the error message which cause the identity management not working ?

Comment: @NanYu Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender' while attempting to activate 'MyProjectName.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'.

Comment: See reply for adding IEmailSender in your DI system .

Answer (score 0):

When registering a new user , asp.net core Identity will invoke the `IEmailSender` service to confirm the email addresss , in `Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Register.cshtml.cs` :

```
await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
   $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");
```

If you don't want to use any of the mail-sending functionality on the default template , you can delete the `IEmailSender` related codes on each pages.

Otherwise , you can follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#implement-iemailsender) to implement `IEmailSender` and register the `IEmailSender` to ASP.NET Core DI container as that document shows .